# Clearcase make vs Gnu make output

Tags: makefile, clearcase, gnu-make

I have this simple Makefile:

```
a:
        touch a

b: a
        touch b

all: b
        touch myapp
```

`make all` returns:

```
touch a
touch b
touch myapp
```

`clearmake all` (or `clearmake -C gnu all`) returns:

```
touch a

touch b

touch myapp
```

How to get rid of the unnecessary newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not many possibility to change the output of [`clearmake`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-1-3&lang=en) (or [`clearmake -C gnu`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/makefile_gnu.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-1-10-2&lang=en))

(`-n` only prints the commands, `-s` does not print it)

That leaves you with workarounds like:

```
clearmake all | grep -v '^$'
```

Comment: @EugeniuRosca Check first with IBM support, just in case.